# Can somebody explain what is wrong with this INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax

Simplified, I have three tables in a MySQL database:

```
sessions
- id
- title
- training_programme_id

session_attendees
- id
- sessions_id
- users_id

users
- id
- name
```

I am trying to count the number of sessions that a user is attending on a given training programme. When a user is set to attend a session, their ID is added to `session_attendees.users_id` and the session ID is added to `session_attendees.sessions_id`. Here is my SQL to count (as `result`) the number of sessions attended by a user with ID `10` when the training programme ID is `1`:

```
SELECT count(*) AS result FROM session_attendees 
   INNER JOIN sessions 
   ON (session_attendees.sessions_id = sessions.id) 
   WHERE (session_attendees.users_id = 10 AND sessions.training_programme_id = 1);
```

Now I know from directly inspecting the database that `session_attendees` contains 7 sessions where `users_id = 10` and all of those sessions have a `training_programme_id = 1`.

Am I misunderstanding an INNER JOIN?

**EDIT:**

Here's a couple of images to illustrate my tables:

[image]

As you can see I've sorted by user ID so you can see the 7 entries for ID = 10.

[image]

Comment: Your sql looks fine ... try a left join to see if it returns you data.

Comment: Why do you suspect your script not being fine? Which is the result you obtain after running it?

Comment: Try setting up the tables and query on http://sqlfiddle.com/ so we can see it working, then maybe it will be more obvious what's going wrong.

Comment: @Garry How many result rows you get if you replace `count(*)` in the select list with `sessions_id`? And which are these?